# The Role "A" was not found and gives System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Actually i have created a role called "A" by using this code:

```
exec aspnet_Roles_CreateRole
@ApplicationName  = 'Application name',
@RoleName         = 'A'
```

And now i need to add this role to a user. There is a list of role in my application and previously it was working with other roles and still good. But this new role is not added and throws the error as:

> System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException: The role 'A' was not found.

This is my C# code:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Find Name
    lblMsg.Visible = false;
    nameLabel.Text = "";
    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
    UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
    PrincipalSearcher srch;

    try
    {
        qbeUser.SamAccountName = userTextBox1.Text;
        srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);
    }
    catch
    {
        lblMsg.Visible = true;
        lblMsg.Text = " Employee filed is Empty !  ";
        lblMsg.CssClass = "faild";

        return;
    }
    foreach (var found in srch.FindAll())
    {
      DirectoryEntry de = found.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

        nameLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(de.Properties["GivenName"].Value);
        principleLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(de.Properties["UserPrincipalName"].Value);
    }
    if (nameLabel.Text == "")
    {
        lblMsg.Visible = true;
        lblMsg.Text = " Username is not found   ";
        lblMsg.CssClass = "faild";
        return;
    }
    List<string> User_Roles_List = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < chkSetup.Items.Count; i++)
        if (chkSetup.Items[i].Selected)
            User_Roles_List.Add(chkSetup.Items[i].Value);
    for (int i = 0; i < chkEmployee.Items.Count; i++)
        if (chkEmployee.Items[i].Selected)
            User_Roles_List.Add(chkEmployee.Items[i].Value);
    for (int i = 0; i < chkShift.Items.Count; i++)
        if (chkShift.Items[i].Selected)
            User_Roles_List.Add(chkShift.Items[i].Value);
    for (int i = 0; i < chkAttendance.Items.Count; i++)
        if (chkAttendance.Items[i].Selected)
            User_Roles_List.Add(chkAttendance.Items[i].Value);
    for (int i = 0; i < chkSite.Items.Count; i++)
        if (chkSite.Items[i].Selected)
            User_Roles_List.Add(chkSite.Items[i].Value);
    for (int i = 0; i < chkPayroll.Items.Count; i++)
        if (chkPayroll.Items[i].Selected)
            User_Roles_List.Add(chkPayroll.Items[i].Value);
    for (int i = 0; i < chkOthers.Items.Count; i++)
        if (chkOthers.Items[i].Selected)
            User_Roles_List.Add(chkOthers.Items[i].Value);

    string[] current_roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(userTextBox1.Text);
    if (current_roles.Length != 0)
        Roles.RemoveUserFromRoles(userTextBox1.Text, current_roles);
    Roles.AddUserToRoles(userTextBox1.Text, User_Roles_List.ToArray());  //Error occur at this line   
    lblMsg.Visible = true;
    lblMsg.CssClass = "successfull";
    lblMsg.Text = "Roles have been successfully updated";
}
```

I have googled a lot but didn't get the actual solution. Can u please tell me where am i making the mistake?

Comment: You added the role to the database but are querying AD for it?

Comment: can u please tell me the process to do after this.....@Amy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you in this case.

In your Microsoft Visual Studio, Go to "Website" and Click "Asp.net Configuration" 
and then in "Security" tab, create new role called `A`.
From there you can manage the role assignments and user too in Asp.net

Comment: Thanks a lot, this method helped me out. @Ragwan